# ¿Cómo cambiar el texto de un option dentro de un select HTML con el método setTimeout() de JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una lista desplegable (select html) y necesito cambiar el texto del  elemento option  que tiene value igual a 0 cada intervalo de tiempo igual a tres segundos.

Escribí este código pero no me funciona ya que la pausa que debería hacer el temporizador de  JavaScript no se está ejecutando.

*(Debería ejecutarse la función y tener un tiempo de espera de tres segundos para volverse a ejecutar)*

Mi código:

```
 var nueva = null;
    var n = 0;
    function  SenialTraductor() { 
        var text = ['Selecionar idioma. . .', 'Select a Language. . .', 'Seleccione Idioma. . .'];
        var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 0));

    if (n < 8 ){
n++;
        console.log(i);    
        $('#traductor option[value='+ 0 + ']').text(text[i]);
        nueva = setTimeout(SenialTraductor(),3000); 
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Pero `setTimeout` solo ejecutará su bloque de código una vez pasado el lapso de tiempo indicado, si deseas que la acción se repita de forma continua en intervalos de tiempo entonces es `setInterval`

Comment: Hola... Aprendiz , por eso en la ultima linea de mi codigo vuelvo a llamar la funcion;

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolver añadiendo la funcion Stop();

```
var nueva = null;
var n = 0;
function SenialTraductor() {
    var text = ['Selecione um idioma. . .', 'Select a Language. . .', 'Seleccione Idioma. . .', 'Selecione um idioma. . .' ,'Select a Language. . .'];
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 0));
    console.log(i);
    $('#traductor option[value=' + 0 + ']').text(text[i]);
    Stop();
    nueva = setInterval(SenialTraductor, 2000);
}

function Stop() {
    clearTimeout(nueva);
}
```